# Limit-Sum problem.

Tags: limits, summation

Here's a limit/sum problem I dreamt up:

$$\lim_{a\to \infty}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac na$$

I have a feeling there is a simple solution, but I'm not sure. Apologies if this question doesn't include enough of my work on the problem; I have no idea where to start.

Comment: Is there an index of summation, or do you mean to say $\lim_{n \to \infty} \lim_{a \to \infty} \frac{n}{a}$?

Comment: The order of limits is what matter here.

Comment: There wasn't an $n$ in the summation when I posted that =)

Answer (score 1):

The infinite sum is $\infty$ for any $0 < a < \infty$.  Therefore the limit as $a \rightarrow \infty$ is still $\infty$.

EDIT: Some work?  Define $b_k := \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{n}{k}$ for each $k \in \mathbb{N}$. Then for each $k$, $b_k > M$ for any $M \in \mathbb{R}$.  Hence,
$$\lim_{k\rightarrow \infty} b_k > M$$
for each $M \in \mathbb{R}$.

Therefore, $b_k \rightarrow \infty$ as $k \rightarrow \infty$.

Comment: Any work to back that up?

Comment: @Tdonut Remember that the order of limit and summation cannot be changed here.

Comment: Tdonut, see my edit.

Comment: Perhaps you're confused about the fact that there's two limits here. Basically, the way you wrote it, the order was very clear. The infinite sum limit was first, then the a goes to infinity limit was second.  In this order, the answer is infinity.  If you switch the order of the  limits, the answer is always zero.